# What is the most efficient way to read and augment (copy samples and change some values) large dataset in .csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, large-data, data-augmentation

Currently, I have managed to solve this but it is slower than what I need. It takes approximately: 1 hour for 500k samples, the entire dataset is ~100M samples, which requires ~200hours for 100M samples.

Hardware/Software specs: RAM 8GB, Windows 11 64bit, Python 3.8.8

The problem:
I have a dataset in .csv (~13GB) where each sample has a value and a respective start-end period of few months.I want to create a dataset where each sample will have the same value but referring to each specific month.

For example:

from:

idx | start date | end date | month | year | value
0 | 20/05/2022 | 20/07/2022 | 0 | 0 | X

to:

0 | 20/05/2022 | 20/07/2022 | 5 | 2022 | X
1 | 20/05/2022 | 20/07/2022 | 6 | 2022 | X
2 | 20/05/2022 | 20/07/2022 | 7 | 2022 | X

Ideas: Manage to do it parallel (like Dask, but I am not sure how for this task).

My implementation:
Chunk read in pandas, augment in dictionaries , append to CSV. Use a function that, given a df, calculates for each sample the months from start date to end date and creates a copy sample for each month appending it to a dictionary. Then it returns the final dictionary.

The calculations are done in dictionaries as they were found to be way faster than doing it in pandas. Then I iterate through the original CSV in chunks and apply the function at each chunk appending the resulting augmented df to another csv.

The function:

```py
def augment_to_monthly_dict(chunk):
    '''
    Function takes a df or subdf  data and creates and returns an Augmented dataset with monthly data in 
    Dictionary form (for efficiency)
    '''
    dict={}
    l=1
    for i in range(len(chunk)):#iterate through every sample
        # print(str(chunk.iloc[i].APO)[4:6] )  
        #Find the months and years period
        mst =int(float((str(chunk.iloc[i].start)[4:6])))#start month
        mend=int(str(chunk.iloc[i].end)[4:6]) #end month
        yst =int(str(chunk.iloc[i].start)[:4] )#start year
        yend=int(str(chunk.iloc[i].end)[:4] )#end year

        if yend==yst:
            months=[ m for m in range(mst,mend+1)]   
            years=[yend for i in range(len(months))]         
        elif yend==yst+1:# year change at same sample
            months=[m for m in range(mst,13)]
            years=[yst for i in range(mst,13)]
            months= months+[m for m in range(1, mend+1)]
            years= years+[yend for i in range(1, mend+1)]
        else:
            continue
        #months is a list of each month in the period of the sample and years is a same 
        #length list of the respective years eg months=[11,12,1,2] , years= 
        #[2021,2022,2022,2022]

        for j in range(len(months)):#iterate through list of months
            #copy the original sample make it a dictionary
            tmp=pd.DataFrame(chunk.iloc[i]).transpose().to_dict(orient='records')

            #change the month and year values accordingly (they were 0 for initiation)

            tmp[0]['month'] = months[j]
            tmp[0]['year'] = years[j]
            # Here could add more calcs e.g. drop irrelevant columns, change datatypes etc 
            #to reduce size
            #
            #-------------------------------------
            #Append new row to the Augmented data
            dict[l] = tmp[0]
            l+=1
    return dict
```

Reading the original dataset (.csv ~13GB), augment using the function and append result to new .csv:

```py
chunk_count=0
for chunk in pd.read_csv('enc_star_logar_ek.csv', delimiter=';', chunksize=10000):

  chunk.index = chunk.reset_index().index

  aug_dict = augment_to_monthly_dict(chunk)#make chunk dictionary to work faster
  chunk_count+=1  

  if chunk_count ==1: #get the column names and open csv write headers and 1st chunk

       #Find the dicts keys, the column names only from the first dict(not reading all data)
       for kk in aug_dict.values():
            key_names = [i for i in kk.keys()] 
            print(key_names)
            break #break after first input dict

       #Open csv file and write ';' separated data
       with open('dic_to_csv2.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,delimiter=';', fieldnames=key_names)
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows(aug_dict.values())

  else: # Save the rest of the data chunks
       print('added chunk: ', chunk_count)
       with open('dic_to_csv2.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,delimiter=';', fieldnames=key_names)
            writer.writerows(aug_dict.values())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas efficiency comes in to play when you need to manipulate *columns* of data, and to do that Pandas reads the input row-by-row building up a series of data for each column; that's a lot of extra computation your problem doesn't benefit from, and in fact just slows your solution down.

You actually need to manipulate *rows*, and for that the fastest way is to use the standard csv module; all you need to do is read a row in, write the derived rows out, and repeat:

```py
import csv
import sys

from datetime import datetime


def parse_dt(s):
    return datetime.strptime(s, r"%d/%m/%Y")


def get_dt_range(beg_dt, end_dt):
    """
    Returns a range of (month, year) tuples, from beg_dt up-to-and-including end_dt.
    """
    if end_dt < beg_dt:
        raise ValueError(f"end {end_dt} is before beg {beg_dt}")

    mo, yr = beg_dt.month, beg_dt.year

    dt_range = []
    while True:
        dt_range.append((mo, yr))
        if mo == 12:
            mo = 1
            yr = yr + 1
        else:
            mo += 1
        if (yr, mo) > (end_dt.year, end_dt.month):
            break

    return dt_range


fname = sys.argv[1]
with open(fname, newline="") as f_in, open("output_csv.csv", "w", newline="") as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerow(next(reader))  # transfer header

    for row in reader:
        beg_dt = parse_dt(row[1])
        end_dt = parse_dt(row[2])
        for mo, yr in get_dt_range(beg_dt, end_dt):
            row[3] = mo
            row[4] = yr
            writer.writerow(row)
```

And, to compare with Pandas in general, let's examine @abokey's specifc Pandas solution—I'm not sure if there is a better Pandas implementation, but this one kinda does the right thing:

```py
import sys
import pandas as pd

fname = sys.argv[1]
df = pd.read_csv(fname)

df["start date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start date"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
df["end date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end date"], format="%d/%m/%Y")

df["month"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: pd.date_range(
        start=x["start date"], end=x["end date"] + pd.DateOffset(months=1), freq="M"
    ).month.tolist(),
    axis=1,
)
df["year"] = df["start date"].dt.year

out = df.explode("month").reset_index(drop=True)

out.to_csv("output_pd.csv")
```

Let's start with the basics, though, do the programs actually do the right thing.  Given this input:

```
idx,start date,end date,month,year,value
0,20/05/2022,20/05/2022,0,0,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,0,0,X
0,20/12/2022,20/01/2023,0,0,X
```

My program, `./main.py input.csv`, produces:

```
idx,start date,end date,month,year,value
0,20/05/2022,20/05/2022,5,2022,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,5,2022,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,6,2022,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,7,2022,X
0,20/12/2022,20/01/2023,12,2022,X
0,20/12/2022,20/01/2023,1,2023,X
```

I believe that's what you're looking for.

The Pandas solution, `./main_pd.py input.csv`, produces:

```
,idx,start date,end date,month,year,value
0,0,2022-05-20,2022-05-20,5,2022,X
1,0,2022-05-20,2022-07-20,5,2022,X
2,0,2022-05-20,2022-07-20,6,2022,X
3,0,2022-05-20,2022-07-20,7,2022,X
4,0,2022-12-20,2023-01-20,12,2022,X
5,0,2022-12-20,2023-01-20,1,2022,X
```

Ignoring the added column for the frame index, and the fact the date format has been changed (I'm pretty sure that can be fixed with some Pandas directive I don't know), it still does the right thing with regards to creating new rows with the appropriate date range.

So, both do the right thing. Now, on to performance. I duplicated your initial sample, just the 1 row, for 1_000_000 and 10_000_000 rows:

```py
import sys

nrows = int(sys.argv[1])
with open(f"input_{nrows}.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write("idx,start date,end date,month,year,value\n")
    for _ in range(nrows):
        f.write("0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,0,0,X\n")
```

I'm running a 2020, M1 MacBook Air with the 2TB SSD (which gives **very good** read/write speeds):

|  | 1M rows (sec, RAM) | 10M rows (sec, RAM) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| csv module | 7.8s, 6MB | 78s, 6MB |
| Pandas | 75s, 569MB | 750s, 5.8GB |

You can see both programs following a linear increase in time-to-run that follows the increase in the size of rows.  The csv module's memory remains constanly non-existent because it's streaming data in-and-out (holding on to virtually nothing); Pandas's memory rises with the size of rows it has to hold so that it can do the actual date-range computations, again on *whole columns*. Also, not shown, but for the 10M-rows Pandas test, Pandas spent nearly 2 minutes just writing the CSV—longer than the csv-module approach took to complete the entire task.

Now, for all my putting-down of Pandas, the solution is far fewer lines, and is probably bug free from the get-go. I did have a problem writing get_dt_range(), and had to spend about 5 minutes thinking about what it actually needed to do and debug it.

You can view my setup with the small test harness, and the results, [here](https://github.com/zacharysyoung/StackOverflow/tree/SO-73762452).

Comment: Zach thank you for your time and effort, very clean and comprehensible comment! Your solution seems to do exactly what I need and the computation efficiency improvement looks very promising. I will comment again once I  manage to implement this successfully.  Thanks again!

Comment: I just implemented your approach and everything works! For 6.9GB (100M rows )- 1740s and the created 'output.csv' takes 33.6 GB, translating to an avg 1 to 4.87 rows augmentation. Thank you for your contribution Zack !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use pandas (or even dask) to return the list of months between two columns of a huge dataset (e.g, .csv ~13GB). First you need to convert your two columns to a datetime by using [**`pandas.to_datetime`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). Then, you can use [**`pandas.date_range`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) to get your list.

Try with this :

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """start date   end date    month   year    value
20/05/2022  20/07/2022  0   0   X
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\t')

df['start date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start date'], format = "%d/%m/%Y")
df['end date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end date'], format = "%d/%m/%Y")

df["month"] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x["start date"], end=x["end date"] + pd.DateOffset(months=1), freq="M").month.tolist(), axis=1)
df['year'] = df['start date'].dt.year

out = df.explode('month').reset_index(drop=True)
```

##### `>>> print(out)`

```
  start date   end date month  year value
0 2022-05-20 2022-07-20     5  2022     X
1 2022-05-20 2022-07-20     6  2022     X
2 2022-05-20 2022-07-20     7  2022     X
```

**Note** : *I tested the code above on a 1 million .csv dataset and it took ~10min to get the output.*

Comment: Thank you for your time. However, df['year'] = df['start date'].dt.year does not seem right as we can have different years, but I will try your recommendation using datetime object to see any significant performance changes. Apart from that, I believe the most time-consuming part is the chunk read and then appending it to the final .csv i.e.: 'dic_to_csv2.csv', therefore I am looking for a more efficient solution regarding this part.

Comment: You can readapt the value of `df['year']` to match your expected output. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can read **very large csv file** with [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_csv.html), then process it (same api as pandas), then convert it to pandas dataframe if you need.
**dask** is perfect when pandas fails due to data size or computation speed. But for data that fits into RAM, pandas can often be faster and easier to use than Dask DataFrame.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

#1. read the large csv

dff = dd.read_csv('path_to_big_csv_file.csv') #return Dask.DataFrame

#if still not enough, try more reducing IO costs:
dff = dd.read_csv('largefile.csv', blocksize=25e6) #use blocksize (number of bytes by which to cut up larger files)
dff = dd.read_csv('largefile.csv', columns=["a", "b", "c"]) #return only columns a, b and c

#2. work with dff, dask has the same api than pandas:
#https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-api.html

#3. then, finally, convert dff to pandas dataframe if you want
df = dff.compute() #return pandas dataframe
```

you can also try other alternatives for reading very large csv files efficiently with high speed & low momory usage:
[pola](https://www.pola.rs), [modin](https://modin.readthedocs.io), [koalas](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
**all those packages, same as dask, use similar api as pandas**.

if you have very big csv file, `pandas read_csv with chunksize` usually don't succeed, and even if if succeed, it will be waist of time and energy

Answer (score 0):

There's a [Table](https://convtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tables.html) helper in [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) library (I must confess, a lib of mine). This helper processes csv files as a stream, using simple `csv.reader` under the hood:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table


def dt_range_to_months(dt_start, dt_end):
    return tuple(
        (year_month // 12, year_month % 12 + 1)
        for year_month in range(
            dt_start.year * 12 + dt_start.month - 1,
            dt_end.year * 12 + dt_end.month,
        )
    )


(
    Table.from_csv("tmp/in.csv", header=True)
    .update(
        year_month=c.call_func(
            dt_range_to_months,
            c.call_func(datetime.strptime, c.col("start date"), "%d/%m/%Y"),
            c.call_func(datetime.strptime, c.col("end date"), "%d/%m/%Y"),
        )
    )
    .explode("year_month")
    .update(
        year=c.col("year_month").item(0),
        month=c.col("year_month").item(1),
    )
    .drop("year_month")
    .into_csv("tmp/out.csv")
)
```

Input/Output:

```
~/o/convtools ❯❯❯ head tmp/in.csv
idx,start date,end date,month,year,value
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,0,0,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,0,0,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,0,0,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,0,0,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,0,0,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,0,0,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,0,0,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,0,0,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,0,0,X
...
~/o/convtools ❯❯❯ head tmp/out.csv
idx,start date,end date,month,year,value
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,5,2022,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,6,2022,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,7,2022,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,5,2022,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,6,2022,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,7,2022,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,5,2022,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,6,2022,X
0,20/05/2022,20/07/2022,7,2022,X
...
```

On my M1 Mac on a file where each row explodes into three it processes 100K of rows per second. In case of 100M rows of the same structure it should take ~ 1000s (< 17 min). Of course it depends on how deep inner by-month cycles are.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, although I don't see any outputs in your comment, the code seems to do exactly what was needed. I will comment again once I implement your solution :)

Comment: hi @AKΛ, I've added input/output to the answer